# TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not DirectoryIterator

Tags: python, machine-learning, vgg-net, conv-neural-network

im beginner on Machine learning and currently trying to apply VGG net for my neural network

Im facing this kind of error which is

**listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not ImageDataGenerator**

Im currently use Jupyter notebook as editor and here is my code that i faced error

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#Training Set
train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train')

#Training Set
valid_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('test')


train_size, validation_size, test_size = 200, 100, 100
img_width, img_height = 224, 224  # Default input size for VGG16

# Extract features
import os, shutil


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 32

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                            target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode='categorical')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_set, train_size)  # Agree with our small dataset size
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, validation_size)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, test_size)
```

this is the error occur

> Found 714 images belonging to 10 classes. Found 100 images belonging
>
> to 10 classes.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        36     return features, labels
>        37 
>   ---> 38 train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_set, train_size)  # Agree with our small dataset size
>        39 validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, validation_size)
>        40 test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, test_size)
>
> in extract_features(directory,
>   sample_count)
>        24                                             target_size=(img_width,img_height),
>        25                                             batch_size = batch_size,
>   ---> 26                                             class_mode='categorical')
>        27     # Pass data through convolutional base
>        28     i = 0
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py
>   in flow_from_directory(self, directory, target_size, color_mode,
>   classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, save_to_dir,
>   save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation)
>       538             follow_links=follow_links,
>       539             subset=subset,
>   --> 540             interpolation=interpolation
>       541         )
>       542
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\directory_iterator.py in **init**(self, directory, image_data_generator, target_size,
>   color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed,
>   data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links,
>   subset, interpolation, dtype)
>       104         if not classes:
>       105             classes = []
>   --> 106             for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
>       107                 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
>       108                     classes.append(subdir)
>
> TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None,
>   not DirectoryIterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a data generator to another data generator, in this line:

```
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                        target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                        class_mode='categorical')
```

first argument, directory, should be a directory, not a data generator, it should be something like: 'path/to/my/train_set/' . which is just 'train' in  your case I guess, since you have them in the same folder as your notebook.